# Open/compact sets in metric $d_1$ and $d_2$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

In a set $X$ we consider two metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$.

We consider that the identity map $f:(X,d_1)\rightarrow (X,d_2)$ with $f(x)=x$ is continuous.

Which of the following statements are correct?

(a) If a set is open as for $d_2$ then it is also open as for $d_1$.

(b) If a set is compact as for $d_2$ then it is also compact as for $d_1$.

(c) A set is open as for $d_1$ iff it is open as for $d_2$.

(d) If a set is open as for $d_1$ then it is open as for $d_2$.

$$$$

I think (d) is correct because for the other statements we would need also that $f$ is surjective, or not?

$$$$

The definition of continuity is:

A function $f:(X,d)\rightarrow (Y,\sigma )$ between two metric spaces is continuous in a point $x_0\in X$ if for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $d(x,x_0)<\delta \Rightarrow \sigma (f(x),f(x_0))<\epsilon$. A function is continuous in each element iff the inverse image of an open (closed) set is open (closed).

Comment: a) is correct and the others are wrong.

Comment: Also, $f$ is surjective, because it is the identity function. But surjectivity has nothing to do with any of these statements.

Comment: Howdo we see that? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Do we use the equivalence of the metrics? Or how do we check that? @MarkKamsma

Comment: I am just pointing out that $f$ is surjective, this has nothing to do with the metrics. Also, the question as you stated it does not mention anything about the metrics being equivalent (in fact, if the metrics were equivalent then all of (a), (b), (c) and (d) would be true).

Comment: By the way, for an answer it might be useful if you add which definition of continuity you are using.

Comment: The definition is : A function $f:(X,d)\rightarrow (Y,\sigma )$ between two metric spaces is continuous in a point $x_0\in X$ if for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $d(x,x_0)<\delta \Rightarrow \sigma (f(x),f(x_0))<\epsilon$. A function is continuous in each element iff the inverse image of an open (closed) set is open (closed). 
@MarkKamsma

Comment: Thanks Mary, can you edit that into your question please? So others don't have to filter through the comments. As a hint: can you use that second characterisation for (a)?

Comment: Let $A$ be open in $(X,d_2)$. Since $f$ is continuous it folds that $f^{-1}(A)$ is again open but in $(X,d_1)$. Since $f$ is the identity map,we get $f^{-1}(A)=A$.So we get that $A$ is open also in $(X,d_1)$. Is that correct? @MarkKamsma

Comment: So (a) is true. For (c) and (d) we have to check the inverse direction. How can we check this one? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: That is right @MaryStar. As for the other parts, someone just posted a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement $(a)$ is true. To see this, let $U$ be a set open for $d_2$. Then, consider the the preimage $f^{-1}(U)$.
Since $f$ is continuous, we must conclude that because $U$ is open, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $d_1$. But, because $f$ is the identity map, we conclude that $f^{-1}(U) = U$.

The other statements are incorrect. To see this, consider the following counter-example:

Let $X = \mathbb{R}$, and suppose that $d_2$ is the standard metric (i.e. $d_2(x,y) = |x-y|$). Let $d_1(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 \ \text{if } x = y\\ 1 \ \text{if } x \neq y\end{cases}
$

It isn't too difficult to show that $d_1$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}$ AND that with these metrics, the identity map $f$ as you prescribed is continuous.
Now, pick a point $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and consider the ball
$B = \{y \in \mathbb{R}: d_1(x,y) < 1\}$. It isn't too hard to see that $B$ is precisely the singleton $\{x\}$ which is open in the topology induced by the metric $d_1$. However, singletons are NOT open in the standard euclidean topology. That is, $\{x\}$ is not open in $d_2$. This immediately rules out statements $(c)$ and $(d)$.

As far as why $(b)$ isn't true, we note that the closed interval $I = [0,1]$ is compact in $d_2$. However, it cannot be compact in $d_1$. Why not? Well, $A = \{ \{x\}\}_{x \in I}$ is an open cover of $I$ (in the metric topology induced by $d_1$) which admits no finite subcover.

**Edit:** To answer some of the questions in the comments, I've included this edit. Let's start with why singletons $\{x\}$ are open in the topology induced by $d_1$. Remember that when we have a metric $d$ on a space $X$, we *define* the metric topology on $X$ induced by $d$ as the topology generated by balls. That is, any set taking the form $\{y \in X: d(x,y) < r\}$ for some $x \in X$ and some $r > 0$ is automatically open, by definition. So, looking back at the set $B$ which I defined in my original answer, we see that the set $B = \{y \in \mathbb{R}: d_1(x,y)<1\}$ takes precisely this form, so it is open, by definition of the metric topology induced by $d_1$. However, we claim that $B = \{x\}$. Why? Well, clearly $d_1(x,x) = 0$ (recall the axioms for a metric), so $x \in B$ by definition of $B$. However, if $y \neq x$, then our definition of $d_1$ tells us that $d_1(x,y) = 1$. Since $d_1(x,y)$ is NOT strictly less than $1$, we conclude that $y$ cannot be in $B$, so it follows that the only element of $B$ is precisely $x$ itself. Hence we have showed that $B$ is open (trivially) and that $B = \{x\}$.

To answer your next question: Why are singletons not open in the standard Euclidean topology? In general, we have to think back to the definition of an open set in a metric topology. We can say the following: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A subset $U \subset X$ is **open** (with respect to the metric topology induced by $d$) if for each $x \in U$ there is a ball $V$ containing $x$ satisfying $V \subset U$. With this definition, it isn't too hard to see why singletons can't be open in the standard Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$: Any ball $V$ containing the point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ cannot be a subset of the singleton $\{x\}$ (balls in the standard Euclidean topology are precisely open intervals on the real line, but no open interval is a subset of a singleton).

Next question: Why is $I = [0,1]$ compact in $d_2$, but not $d_1$? A simple way to see that $I$ is compact (in $d_2$) is by invoking the **Heine-Borel Theorem:**

> A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact (in the standard topology) iff it is closed and bounded.

Why is $I$ bounded? Well, $d_2(0,y) < 2$ for all $y \in I$ (i.e. there is a ball, centered at $0$ in our case, which contains $I$). I leave it as an exercise for you to show that $I$ is closed. Depending on which definition of closed you are working with, you may either have to show that the complement of $I$ (that is $\mathbb{R} \setminus I = (-\infty, 0) \cup (1, \infty))$ is open using the definition I gave above, or you may have to show that $I$ contains its limit points (being closed has many equivalent definitions). Ultimately, it ends up being a standard fact that all closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ are compact.

While the Heine-Borel theorem gives us a nice way to view compact subsets of Euclidean spaces, compactness can be defined more generally for arbitrary metric spaces $(X,d)$ (I limit myself to metric spaces since you have this question posted under the analysis tag) in the following way:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. An **open cover** of $X$ is a family $A = \{A_j\}_{j \in J}$ of open subsets of $X$ (i.e. each $A_j \subset X$ is open) satisfying $$X \subset \bigcup_{j \in J} A_j$$
Here, $J$ is just an arbitrary indexing set. Then, $X$ is **compact** if every open cover $A$ of $X$ has a finite subcover (i.e. if $A$ is an open cover of $X$, then there exists a finite subset $B \subset A$ such that $B$ is an open cover of $X$).

With these definitions, it is easy to see that the set $A = \{\{x\}\}_{x \in I}$ which I defined in my original answer is an open cover of $I$ (in $d_1)$. In $d_1$, we proved that singletons are open, so $A$ consists of open subsets of $I$. Also, $$I = \bigcup_{x \in I} \{x\}$$

Hence, $A$ satisfies the definition of an open cover of $I$. However, no finite subcover exists. Why? For a contradiction, suppose a finite subcover $B = \{\{x_i\}\}_{i=1}^n \subset A$ exists. Then, by definition of an open cover, $$I \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n \{x_i\}$$
But this inclusion is impossible since $I$ contains infinitely many elements while the set on the right hand side of the inclusion is finite. Thus, no finite subcover of $A$ exists, hence $I$ cannot be compact in $d_1$.

Comment: Why is the singleton $\{x\}$ open in the topology induced by the metric $d_1$ and why is it not open in the standard euclidean topology?

Comment: Why is $I$ compact in $d_2$ and not in $d_1$ ?

Comment: Why is $A$ an open cover of $I$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar I have expanded by original post to answer some of your further questions.

Comment: Why does $I$ contain infinitely many elements? Isn't it a closed interval?

Comment: Intervals are sets: $I = [0,1] = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$. There are infinitely many real numbers between 0 and 1